# add images to randomised backstretch set - jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using backstretch to display images as backgrounds on a sites body, as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var images = [
    "/path/to/img1",
    "/path/to/img2",
    "/path/to/img3",
    "/path/to/img4",
    "/path/to/img5",
  ];

  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }

  images = shuffle(images);

  $("body").backstretch([
    images[0],
    images[1],
    images[2],
    images[3],
    images[4],
  ],{
    duration:10000,
    fade:3000,
  });
});
```

I used shuffle() to randomise the order of the images in the image array, so that when the page is loaded a random image is used, and then changes in a randomised order.

What I am looking for, is a way to be able to add images to the array. At the moment the backstretch function uses a known index length, but if I add one more image to the array, i also need to add another image[index] inside the backstretched array.

Any ideas for how to go about this?

much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

In WordPress (probably should have mentioned that earlier), I use wp_localize_script() function after I enqueue the script. Then I can pass in values as an array.

```
wp_localize_script( 
    'script_handle', 
    'object_name_inside_script', 
    $array_of_values_to_pass_in 
);
```

Now I have an array that I can work with.